# Adding Ordinal Contractions to $i

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php display number with ordinal suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/php-display-number-with-ordinal-suffix)

I'm attempting to add ordinal contractions i.e.(st/nd/rd/th) to an increment.

Somehow I need to get the last digit of $i to test it against my if statements...

Here is my code so far:

```
    $i = 1;
    while($i < 101 ){

    if($i == 1){$o_c = "st";}else{$o_c = "th";}
    if($i == 2){$o_c = "nd";}
    if($i == 3){$o_c = "rd";}

    echo $i.$o_c."<br/>";
    $i++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulus (%) operator to get the remainder when dividing by 10.

```
$i = 1;
while($i < 101 ){

$remainder = $i % 10;
if($remainder == 1){$o_c = "st";}else{$o_c = "th";}
if($remainder == 2){$o_c = "nd";}
if($remainder == 3){$o_c = "rd";}

echo $i.$o_c."<br/>";
$i++;

}
```

Comment: That answer does not work unless 11st is correct (should be 11th). See the duplicate comment to your question.

Comment: Good point.  You'd need to special case when i%100 is between 11 & 13

Comment: @AlexDeem. 111st isn't correct either. You always need to check the last two digits.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php): `$i % 10`?

Answer (score 0):

[Display numbers with ordinal suffix in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/php-display-number-with-ordinal-suffix/3110033#3110033)

(that thread has other solutions. I liked that one)