# add 'rd or 'th or 'st dependent on number

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display numbers with ordinal suffix in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/php-display-number-with-ordinal-suffix)

I think they are called Ordinal suffixes.

Have seen examples for dates...

But just wondered if there was some php that can spew out the suffix dependant on number.

Example: we are spewing out the leaderboard score of our users.

So member ranked number 1. we wish to echo: 1'st
and member ranked 847. we want to spew out 847'th

etc etc

I cannot give example, as the numbers are rendered on page via our dB

Just wondered if there was some sort of code snippet, that could add automagically 'th or 'st or 'rd to the appropriate number.

Comment: NB: Don't use an apostrophe. Convention is `4th` or `4<sup>th</sup>` and not `4'th`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't know of any built-ins that do this, but this should work:

```
function ordinal_suffix($num){
    $num = $num % 100; // protect against large numbers
    if($num < 11 || $num > 13){
         switch($num % 10){
            case 1: return 'st';
            case 2: return 'nd';
            case 3: return 'rd';
        }
    }
    return 'th';
}
```

(note 11, 12 and 13 are special cases - 11th, 12th, 13th vs 11st...)

Comment: you can optimize 'if' statement with if($num < 4 || $num > 20)

Comment: This doesn't work for "112", etc. Add: while ($num > 100) {$num -= 100}

Comment: @user1023127 you're better off just tacking in a `$num = $num % 100` line than the while loop. edited above.