# Add Ordinal Suffix to WordPress Counter

Tags: wordpress, counter, ordinal, ordinals

I am trying to add ordinal suffixes to a WordPress Post Counter that I am building for a ranking board. Here is the code I currently have.

```
<?php if(have_posts()): $counter = 1; query_posts('post_type=rushmoor&meta_key=subaru_driver_best_lap&orderby=meta_value_num&order=asc'); while(have_posts()):the_post();?>
<?php $driver_best_lap = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'subaru_driver_best_lap', true );?>
<li>
    <div class="name"><?php echo $counter;?> <?php the_title();?></div>
    <div class="lap-time"><?php echo $driver_best_lap;?></div>
</li>         
<?php $counter++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif;?>
```

I have been trying to merge code from the following link with the above, however I cannot yield anything that actually works and am wondering if anyone can assist.

[add 'rd or 'th or 'st dependant on number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604904/add-rd-or-th-or-st-dependant-on-number)

Thanks
Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the `ordinal_suffix` function from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6604934/1832106) to your WordPress [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file so you can use it in your theme. Then you want to pass your `$counter` output to it. You'll want to change that line to:

```
<div class="name"><?php echo ordinal_suffix($counter);?> <?php the_title();?></div>
```

Comment: Perfect. I tried something like this but got one little bit wrong. Glad to see I was at least on the right track :)