# WordPress - Trying to split todays posts into morning & afternoon with counter

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, conditional-statements, counter

I have a WordPress function that allows me to displays "Todays" posts on a page and I am trying to take it further to split it into "Morning" and "Afternoon".

Here is the code I am using for Todays Posts:

```
function my_posts_where_from_today( $where = '' ) {
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now')) . "'";
return $where;
}
```

This sits in functions.php and I call the filter within the post.

I am also using ordinal suffixes that are dynamically generated as shown in this question:

[Add Ordinal Suffix to WordPress Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274562/add-ordinal-suffix-to-wordpress-counter)

In order to split my posts into morning/afternoon, here is what I am doing:

```
<?php if(have_posts()): $counter = 1;?>
<?php query_posts('post_type=rushmoor&meta_key=subaru_driver_best_lap&orderby=meta_value_num&order=asc');?>
<?php while(have_posts()):the_post();?>
<?php $driver_best_lap = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'subaru_driver_best_lap', true );?>
<?php $gmt_timestamp = get_post_time('H'); ?>
<?php if ($gmt_timestamp < 12) {?>
<li>
  <div class="rank"><?php echo $counter;?><?php echo ordinal_suffix($counter);?></div>
  <div class="name">
    <?php the_title();?>
  </div>
  <div class="lap-time"><?php echo $driver_best_lap;?></div>
</li>
<?php }?>       
<?php $counter++; endwhile;?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Afternoon:

```
<?php if(have_posts()): $counter = 1;?>
<?php query_posts('post_type=rushmoor&meta_key=subaru_driver_best_lap&orderby=meta_value_num&order=asc');?>
<?php while(have_posts()):the_post();?>
<?php $driver_best_lap = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'subaru_driver_best_lap', true );?>
<?php $gmt_timestamp = get_post_time('H'); ?>
<?php if ($gmt_timestamp > 12 && $gmt_timestamp < 24) {?>
<li>
  <div class="rank"><?php echo $counter;?><?php echo ordinal_suffix($counter);?></div>
  <div class="name">
    <?php the_title();?>
  </div>
  <div class="lap-time"><?php echo $driver_best_lap;?></div>
</li>
<?php }?>       
<?php $counter++; endwhile;?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

The problem is that my counter is getting messed up.

See the following links for examples:

http://www.subarurallyexperience.co.uk/rushmoor/ranking/today/ (shows all todays posts perfectly)
http://www.subarurallyexperience.co.uk/rushmoor/ranking/today/morning/ (shows only morning posts, but counter is messed up)
http://www.subarurallyexperience.co.uk/rushmoor/ranking/today/afternoon/ (shows only afternoon posts, but counter is messed up)

I have been trying for like an hour to fix the counter, but I cannot seem to get it working.

Would appreciate any help as this is doing my head in!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the part where you increment the counter in the `if` loop:

```
  ...
</li>
<?php $counter++; ?>
<?php } ?>       
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Oh great. The answer was staring me in the face all along. :/