# Ranking with Echo on Php

Tags: php, echo, ranking

My problem is very very basic, however I don't have enough knowledge to fix it.
My code:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat' => '22', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'my_meta_key',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'fields' => 'ids'
));

global $post; // current post object

$i = array_search( $post->ID, $query->posts ) + 1;

echo '<div class="ranks">';
echo '<a href="...">Post Ranking: </a>'; 
echo "{$i}th"; 
echo '</div>';
```

I couldn't manage write codes for {$i}st (1st), {$i}nd (2nd) and {$i}rd (3rd). Will appreciate any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604904/add-rd-or-th-or-st-dependant-on-number

Comment: Thanks I flagged it and also fixed the problem.