# Yii: CNumberFormatter to be use to format numbers in ordinal style

Tags: yii, numbers

I've been reading Yii's docs about `CNumberFormatter` and I didn't found any documentation about formatting a number in an ordinal way. So my question is:

Is it entirely possible to format a number using Yii's built-in `CNumberFormatter` class in an ordinal manner.

```
Example: $number = 1 -> format to ordinal -> returns `1st`.
```

If yes, how?

Comment: Currently Yii doesn't have this function, you need to write extra method to do it.

Comment: @chen That's just sad. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your own formatter class, add code from [Display numbers with ordinal suffix in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3109978/584192):

```
<?php    
class CustomFormatter extends CFormatter {

    public function formatOrdinal($value) {
        $ends = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');
        if (($value%100) >= 11 && ($value%100) <= 13)
           return $value. 'th';
        else
           return $value. $ends[$value % 10];
    }
}
```

Implement it in Yii's main.php config file:

```
// application components
'components' => array(
    'format' => array(
        'class' => 'application.extensions.CustomFormatter',
     ),

     ...
```