# Accurately setting up a ranking from an single dimension array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to display some array data in relation to a competition, each player is ranked by the number of points they have, however if a player has the same amount of points to somebody else they should both have the exact same ranking position.

For instance...

```
1st     Bob     500pts
2nd     Joe     350pts
3rd     Tom     250pts
3rd     Tim     250pts
5th     Jay     100pts
```

In this instance, as Tom & Tim have the exact same number of points they should be joint third, making the next person down 5th (rather than 4th), can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this with a simple array similar to follows

```
array('Bob' => 500, 'Joe' => '350', 'Tom' => '250', 'Tim' => '250', 'Jay' => '100');
```

Can anyone suggest the 'cleanest' solution for achieving this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work for you:

```
$array = array('Bob' => 500, 'Joe' => '350', 'Tom' => '250', 'Tim' => '250', 'Jay' => '100');
arsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);

$previousPoints = null;
$position = $total = 1;
foreach($array as $name=>$points) {
   if ($points != $previousPoints) {
       $position = $total;
   }

   echo $position.' '.$name.' '.$points."\n";

   $previousPoints = $points;
   $total++;
}
```

Online [demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4f41f7c876ebae5616a1a7e640288e61f4940f5).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$a = array('Bob' => 500, 'Joe' => '350', 'Tom' => '250', 'Tim' => '250', 'Jay' => '100');
arsort($a);

$rank = 1;
$index = 1;
$prevUserPoints = 0;
foreach($a as $name=>$points) {
    if($points != $prevUserPoints) {
        $rank = $index;
    }
    $index++;
    echo $rank . ' ' . $name . ' ' . $points . "\n";
    $prevUserPoints = $points;
}
```

For displaying 1 as 1st, 2 as 2nd etc, you can use something like below:

```
function ordSuffix($n) {
  $str = "$n";
  $t = $n > 9 ? substr($str,-2,1) : 0;
  $u = substr($str,-1);
  if ($t==1) return $str . 'th';
    else switch ($u) {
      case 1: return $str . 'st';
      case 2: return $str . 'nd';
      case 3: return $str . 'rd';
      default: return $str . 'th';
  }
}
```

example:  `echo ordSuffix(23);` This prints `23rd`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar = array(
    'Bob' => 500,
    'Tim' => '250',
    'Joe' => '350',
    'Tom' => '250',
    'Jay' => '100'
);

arsort($ar, SORT_NUMERIC);

$i = 1;
$previous = 1;
$previousPosition = 1;

foreach($ar as $k => $v)
{
    if($v === $previous)
    {
        //If the value now is the same as the previous value use the previous position
        echo "Position: $previousPosition, $k : $v <br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Position: $i, $k : $v <br />";
    }


    //Previous value
    $previous = $v;

    //Previous Position
    $previousPosition = $i;


    //Always increment the value
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't skip to `5` for `Jay`.

Comment: @cOle2 I have edited and tested the code, if you need nth, nrd etc please refer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/php-display-number-with-ordinal-suffix

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic and alternative point of view you might want to consider.

```
$arr = [
    "Joe" => "350",
    "Tom" => "250",
    "Jay" => "200",   
    "Tim" => "250",
    "Bob" => "500",
    "John" => "250" ,
    "Paul" => "251.40" 
];

$rank = array();

array_walk($arr,function($v, $k) use (&$rank)
{
    if(isset($rank[$v]))
    {
        $rank[$v][$k] = $v;
        asort($rank[$v]); //alphabetical order John, Tim, Tom
    } else 
    {
        $rank[$v] = array($k => $v);
    }
});

krsort($rank);

var_dump(array_values($rank));
```