# Get only ordinal suffix with NumberFormatter

Tags: php, icu, numberformatter

Is it possible to get only the suffix of a number with the NumberFormatter class in PHP.

For example:

```
$nf = new NumberFormatter( 'en', NumberFormatter::ORDINAL );
$out = $nf->format( 10000 );
echo $out . "\n";
```

Will result in: '10,000th'

I would just like: 'th', i.e. the suffix.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that is possible with NumberFormatter, the best you could do would be to grab the last two characters:

```
echo substr($out, -2);
```

Otherwise skip NumberFormatter and [find the suffix a different way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/display-numbers-with-ordinal-suffix-in-php)

Comment: It seems you are correct. I need this for different locales, so it seems it will be a job for preg_replace