# How to add "er" after particular days of the month in php?

Tags: php, date, datetime, numbers, french

I am working on a **html/php** code as shown below:

```
<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='fr'){  ?>  /* When the page is in French */
   <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr(date_format($ts, 'H:i d-m-Y')) ?>"
           data-timezone="<?php echo esc_attr($tz_param) ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(date_i18n( 'j F H:i', $ts->getTimeStamp()-(60*60*4))); ?>
   </time>
<?php }  ?>
```

The above **html/php** code displays the following date/time on the webpage:

```
1 mars 2019 03:45
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **html/php code** above when days of the month is `"1"` then substitute `"1er"`. eg:

`1er mars 2019`

Comment: try with jS in code. echo ucfirst(date_i18n( 'jS F H:i', $ts->getTimeStamp()-(60*60*4)));

Comment: @user3616545 what did you change ?

Comment: Think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/display-numbers-with-ordinal-suffix-in-php.

Comment: The difference is to use `jS` instead of just `j` in the format - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33954806/1213708