# How do I make PHP output "1st", "2nd", "3rd", etc., for 1, 2, 3, based on the language/locale?

Tags: php

Recently, I had to delete enormous amounts of code which I had painstakingly coded but which already existed inside PHP. For example, I had a function to spell out numbers, such as "56" => "fifty-six". PHP has this built in, supporting any locale/language. It was much better than my built-in function. Example:

```
$a = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
var_dump($a->format('3'));
```

Outputs:

```
three
```

Now I'm potentially facing this issue again. I don't want to hardcode in 1 => "1st", 2 = "2nd", 3 = "3rd", 4 = "4th", etc. as English, only to then find out that PHP can do it automatically for any language! Is that the case?

To be extremely clear, I want to input "2" to a function and have it spit out "2nd" if the locale is en_US, and whatever else if a different language/locale, as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/display-numbers-with-ordinal-suffix-in-php).

```
$locale = 'en_US';
$nf = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
echo $nf->format($number);
```

Comment: If you believe that this is a duplicate, than it should be flagged as such instead of just copying the answer here.