# Display date with ordinal suffix in PHP

Tags: php

I am currently displaying date in my php code like below

```
$date = $news_row['date'];
$newDate = date("l M d Y", strtotime($date));
```

its giving me output like

> Monday Mar 08 2021

Instead I want output like

> Monday Mar 08th 2021

I have found function

```
function ordinal($number) {
    $ends = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');
    if ((($number % 100) >= 11) && (($number%100) <= 13))
        return $number. 'th';
    else
        return $number. $ends[$number % 10];
}
```

on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3110033/15218032)

But I am not getting idea how I can use it with my date format. Let me know if anyone here can help me for do it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify any character that you want:

```
$newDate = date("l M d\t\h Y", strtotime($date));
```

But if you want to get `1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th ...` you should use:

```
$newDate = date("l M jS Y", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: but it will always th, I want dynamic which can be th, st and nd etc as per function given in question. Thanks!

Comment: @Mira you did not indicate that in the question!

Comment: wow! Thanks a lot! its work like charm without use that function. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

```
$newDate = date('l M jS Y', strtotime($date));
```

Read about more datetime formats in PHP

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
l => A full textual representation of the day of the week

M=> A short textual representation of a month, three letters, 

j => Day of the month without leading zeros

S => English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters

Y => A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
```

Comment: Thanks! I have up voted it, since Amir have already given right answer, I am not able to accept it as multiple time. Thanks!