# How to make "it is the 10th day." format with date() of php?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date object and want to show it as this format `it is the 10th day.` in my application.

Fore example I want this `it is the 10th day.` to be dynamically generated.

```
it is the 10th day.
it is the 11th day.
it is the 12th day.
# and so on
```

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far, where did you fail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display date with ordinal suffix in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66620609/display-date-with-ordinal-suffix-in-php)

Comment: @Don'tPanic I wanted to format it by date function, sounds a little confusing but I have a special case that requires that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you don't want use the concatenation in PHP and you can use the following format, (It is possible to do like follow)

```
date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
```

Note: use the `\` after the each character to get it done and the `jS` part of format is only thing with get generated

Also if your experimenting with `data()` you will have option to use `PHP` concatenation as well.

```
$date =  "it is the ".date('jS')." day";
```

Comment: also you can do like this as well `$mydate = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');` to use it other places

Comment: Why on earth put the plain text as part of the format?  `echo "it is the " . date('jS') . " day\n";`

Comment: @Don'tPanic actually that's how I want to format it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic there is not problem if some one experimenting some thing

Comment: @A47 "*that's how I want to format it*" - if you find yourself needing to put text unrelated to formatting as a format string, there is probably a better way.  If you had included any details in your question, we could help you.