# How to get word for number with it's ordinal suffix in php or laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

For eg. If I enter 1 the result will be first and if I enter 5, the result will be fifth

I really don't get any idea about how to solve this problem. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Not really seeing where you describe a problem. Is this homework?

Comment: You may have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3110033/9213182

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about ordinal suffix, then for PHP 5.3+, the built-in [Number Formatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) can be used

```php
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,67,789];
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en-US', NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);

foreach($numbers as $num) {
    echo $formatter->format($num);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

/**
//Will output the following

1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
67th
789th
*/
```

And if you want the result in words as **first, fifth** and so on you can

```php
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en-US', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$formatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET, "%spellout-ordinal");

$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,21,67,789,2041];

foreach($numbers as $num) {
    echo echo $num . ": " .$formatter->format($num);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

/**
Will output
1: first
2: second
3: third
4: fourth
5: fifth
21: twenty-first
67: sixty-seventh
789: seven hundred eighty-ninth
2041: two thousand forty-first
*/
```