# php foreach count rows with style positions

Tags: php

I'm trying to create Contest list of users in php.

But my code style don't give me what I want

My code:

```
<?php

$users = ["129292199", "616161616", "272727272", "555554433", "666665886"];
$count = 0;

foreach ($users as $name){
    $count += 1;
    echo  "{$count} $name\n";
}

?>
```

My code output

```
1 129292199
2 616161616
3 272727272
4 555554433
5 666665886
```

But I want something like this

```
 1st : 5453674081
 2nd : 135678975
 3rd : 5607170108
4️⃣ 4th : 1460057759
5️⃣ 5th : 1664868970
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/display-numbers-with-ordinal-suffix-in-php for how to display numbers like `1st`. And add an `<img>` before the number with a URL that points to the appropriate image for each place.

Comment: @Barmar how can I use normal keyboard emoji to do it instead of image

Comment: You can just echo the emoji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap the count variable inside a class and style it with css