# NSNumberFormatter and 'th' 'st' 'nd' 'rd' (ordinal) number endings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

Is there a way to use NSNumberFormatter to get the 'th' 'st' 'nd' 'rd' number endings?

EDIT:

Looks like it does not exist. Here's what I'm using.

```
+(NSString*)ordinalNumberFormat:(NSInteger)num{
    NSString *ending;

    int ones = num % 10;
    int tens = floor(num / 10);
    tens = tens % 10;
    if(tens == 1){
        ending = @"th";
    }else {
        switch (ones) {
            case 1:
                ending = @"st";
                break;
            case 2:
                ending = @"nd";
                break;
            case 3:
                ending = @"rd";
                break;
            default:
                ending = @"th";
                break;
        }
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@", num, ending];
}
```

Adapted from nickf's answer here
[Is there an easy way in .NET to get "st", "nd", "rd" and "th" endings for numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262/is-there-an-easy-way-in-net-to-get-st-nd-rd-and-th-endings-for-numbers)

Comment: This was really useful. I created a gist with this code as an NSString category: https://gist.github.com/3119444

Comment: Is the `floor` call needed? Casting `num / 10` to an `int` should remove anything after the decimal. Right?

Comment: This is now possible with `numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterOrdinalStyle` in iOS 9: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37106084/746890

Comment: I agree with Chris Nolet, this answer should be changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the question asked for a number formatter, here's a rough one I made.

```
//
//  OrdinalNumberFormatter.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface OrdinalNumberFormatter : NSNumberFormatter {

}

@end
```

and the implementation:

```
//
//  OrdinalNumberFormatter.m
//

#import "OrdinalNumberFormatter.h"


@implementation OrdinalNumberFormatter

- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(id *)anObject forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(NSString **)error {
    NSInteger integerNumber;
    NSScanner *scanner;
    BOOL isSuccessful = NO;
    NSCharacterSet *letters = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];

    scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
    [scanner setCaseSensitive:NO];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:letters];

    if ([scanner scanInteger:&integerNumber]){
        isSuccessful = YES;
        if (anObject) {
            *anObject = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:integerNumber];
        }
    } else {
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to create number from %@", string];
        }
    }

    return isSuccessful;
}

- (NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id)anObject {
    if (![anObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *strRep = [anObject stringValue];
    NSString *lastDigit = [strRep substringFromIndex:([strRep length]-1)];

    NSString *ordinal;


    if ([strRep isEqualToString:@"11"] || [strRep isEqualToString:@"12"] || [strRep isEqualToString:@"13"]) {
        ordinal = @"th";
    } else if ([lastDigit isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        ordinal = @"st";
    } else if ([lastDigit isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        ordinal = @"nd";
    } else if ([lastDigit isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        ordinal = @"rd";
    } else {
        ordinal = @"th";
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", strRep, ordinal];
}

@end
```

Instantiate this as an Interface Builder object and attach the Text Field's formatter outlet to it. For finer control (such as setting maximum and minimum values, you should create an instance of the formatter, set the properties as you wish and attach it to text field using it's `setFormatter:` method.

You can [download the class from GitHub](https://github.com/Abizern/ADNOrdinalNumberFormatter) (including an example project)

Comment: @Abizem like jan pointed it this misses some of the teens however I see that it is fixed in your GitHub repo i.e. [strRepresentation hasSuffix:@"11"]

Comment: Thanks @Abizern! Gist with Abizern's code translated into Swift: https://gist.github.com/yoiang/bad782fb55a3cb8d062e

Answer (score 44):

The correct way to do this from iOS 9 onwards, is:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterOrdinalStyle;

NSLog(@"%@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(1)]); // 1st
NSLog(@"%@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(2)]); // 2nd
NSLog(@"%@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(3)]); // 3rd, etc.
```

Alternatively:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString localizedStringFromNumber:@(1)
                                     numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterOrdinalStyle]); // 1st
```

Comment: There is also `NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: n, number: .ordinal)` already from (I think) iOS 4 onwards.

Comment: That method (`localizedStringFromNumber:numberStyle:` in Objective-C) has been around for a while, but they only added `.ordinal` (or `NSNumberFormatterOrdinalStyle`) in iOS9 unfortunately. You can use that form if you're targetting iOS 9 onwards, though.

Answer (score 27):

As of iOS 9

**Swift 4**

```
private var ordinalFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
    return formatter
}()

extension Int {
    var ordinal: String? {
        return ordinalFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self))
    }
}
```

It's probably best to have the formatter outside the extension...

Comment: Swift 3 version would be...

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
    formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value))

Comment: Cheers.. though you could just edit... and maybe have just written the correction rather than the entire thing.

Answer (score 22):

This does the trick in one method (for English). Thanks nickf https://stackoverflow.com/a/69284/1208690 for original code in PHP, I just adapted it to `objective C`:-

```
-(NSString *) addSuffixToNumber:(int) number
{
    NSString *suffix;
    int ones = number % 10;
    int tens = (number/10) % 10;

    if (tens ==1) {
        suffix = @"th";
    } else if (ones ==1){
        suffix = @"st";
    } else if (ones ==2){
        suffix = @"nd";
    } else if (ones ==3){
        suffix = @"rd";
    } else {
        suffix = @"th";
    }

    NSString * completeAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@", number, suffix];
    return completeAsString;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Other Swift solutions do not produce correct result and contain mistakes.
I have translated CmKndy solution to Swift

```
extension Int {

    var ordinal: String {
        var suffix: String
        let ones: Int = self % 10
        let tens: Int = (self/10) % 10
        if tens == 1 {
            suffix = "th"
        } else if ones == 1 {
            suffix = "st"
        } else if ones == 2 {
            suffix = "nd"
        } else if ones == 3 {
            suffix = "rd"
        } else {
            suffix = "th"
        }
        return "\(self)\(suffix)"
    }

}
```

test result:
0th
1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
6th
7th
8th
9th
10th
11th
12th
13th
14th
15th
16th
17th
18th
19th
20th
21st
22nd
23rd

Answer (score 14):

-- Swift 4/5 --

```
     let num = 1
     let formatter = NumberFormatter()
     formatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
     let day = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: num))
     
     print(day!)
     result - 1st
```

Answer (score 7):

It's quite simple in English. Here's a swift extension:

```
extension Int {
    var ordinal: String {
        get {
            var suffix = "th"
            switch self % 10 {
                case 1:
                    suffix = "st"
                case 2:
                    suffix = "nd"
                case 3:
                    suffix = "rd"
                default: ()
            }
            if 10 < (self % 100) && (self % 100) < 20 {
                suffix = "th"
            }
            return String(self) + suffix
        }
    }
}
```

Then call something like:

```
    cell.label_position.text = (path.row + 1).ordinal
```

Comment: This would create 13rd instead of 13th, 12nd instead 12th.

Comment: Thanks @Swinny89 - it's fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding another implementation as a class method.  I didn't see this question posted until after I implemented this from an example in php.

```
+ (NSString *)buildRankString:(NSNumber *)rank
{
    NSString *suffix = nil;
    int rankInt = [rank intValue];
    int ones = rankInt % 10;
    int tens = floor(rankInt / 10);
    tens = tens % 10;
    if (tens == 1) {
        suffix = @"th";
    } else {
        switch (ones) {
            case 1 : suffix = @"st"; break;
            case 2 : suffix = @"nd"; break;
            case 3 : suffix = @"rd"; break;
            default : suffix = @"th";
        }
    }
    NSString *rankString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", rank, suffix];
    return rankString;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a compact Swift extension suitable for all integer types:

```
extension IntegerType {
    func ordinalString() -> String {
        switch self % 10 {
        case 1...3 where 11...13 ~= self % 100: return "\(self)" + "th"
        case 1:    return "\(self)" + "st"
        case 2:    return "\(self)" + "nd"
        case 3:    return "\(self)" + "rd"
        default:   return "\(self)" + "th"
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let numbers = (0...30).map { $0.ordinalString() }
print(numbers.joinWithSeparator(", "))
```

Output:

> 0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th, 15th, 16th, 17th, 18th, 19th, 20th, 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 24th, 25th, 26th, 27th, 28th, 29th, 30th

Comment: ~= what does this operator do?

Comment: ~= is a built-in pattern match operator, in this case it checks if `self % 100` falls in the range `[11...13]`, to handle the "tenths" case correctly. 

For more info see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html

Comment: It's been there since swift 1.x I believe ;)

Comment: I meant the link you shared, it words the whole patterns thing in a new way which wasn't there before

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple solution for this

Swift

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
let first = formatter.string(from: 1) // 1st
let second = formatter.string(from: 2) // 2nd
```

Obj-c

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterOrdinalStyle;
NSString* first = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(1)]; // 1st
NSString* second = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(2)]; // 2nd
```

Referance: [hackingwithswift.com](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-format-dates-with-an-ordinal-suffix-using-numberformatters-ordinalstyle)

Comment: is there a way to get it as first / second , third etc

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of this capability.  However, it's possible to do this yourself.  In English, the ordinal (th, st, nd, rd, etc) has a really simple pattern:

If the number ends with:  => Use:

- 0 => th
- 1 => st
- 2 => nd
- 3 => rd
- 4 => th
- 5 => th
- 6 => th
- 7 => th
- 8 => th
- 9 => th
- 11 => th
- 12 => th
- 13 => th

This will not spell out the word for you, but it will allow you to do something like: "42nd", "1,340,697th", etc.

This gets more complicated if you need it localized.

Comment: This misses some of the teens. I found the algorithm here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262/is-there-an-easy-way-in-net-to-get-st-nd-rd-and-th-endings-for-numbers
Just thought maybe the formatter could handle.

Comment: @jan good point about 11, 12, and 13.  Those suffixes could easily be special-cased.

Answer (score 3):

A clean Swift version (for English only):

```
func ordinal(number: Int) -> String {
    if (11...13).contains(number % 100) {
        return "\(number)th"
    }
    switch number % 10 {
        case 1: return "\(number)st"
        case 2: return "\(number)nd"
        case 3: return "\(number)rd"
        default: return "\(number)th"
    }
}
```

Can be done as an extension for `Int`:

```
extension Int {

    func ordinal() -> String {
        return "\(self)\(ordinalSuffix())"
    }

    func ordinalSuffix() -> String {
        if (11...13).contains(self % 100) {
            return "th"
        }
        switch self % 10 {
            case 1: return "st"
            case 2: return "nd"
            case 3: return "rd"
            default: return "th"
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following example demonstrates how to handle any number. It's in c# however it can easily converted to any language.

http://www.bytechaser.com/en/functions/b6yhfyxh78/convert-number-to-ordinal-like-1st-2nd-in-c-sharp.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This will convert date to string and also add ordinal in the date. You can modify the date formatte by changing **NSDateFormatter** object

```
-(NSString*) getOrdinalDateString:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSString* string=@"";
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date];

    if(components.day == 1 || components.day == 21 || components.day == 31)
        string = @"st";

    else if (components.day == 2 || components.day == 22)
        string = @"nd";

    else if (components.day == 3 || components.day == 23)
        string = @"rd";

    else
        string = @"th";


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatte = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatte setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [dateFormatte setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"d'%@' MMMM yyyy",string]];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatte stringFromDate:date];
    return dateString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Swift solution that cycles through the user's preferred languages until it finds one with known rules (which are pretty easy to add) for ordinal numbers:

```swift
    extension Int {
        var localizedOrdinal: String {

            func ordinalSuffix(int: Int) -> String {
                for language in NSLocale.preferredLanguages() as [String] {

                switch language {
                    case let l where l.hasPrefix("it"):
                        return "°"
                    case let l where l.hasPrefix("en"):
                        switch int {
                        case let x where x != 11 && x % 10 == 1:
                            return "st"
                        case let x where x != 12 && x % 10 == 2:
                            return "nd"
                        case let x where x != 13 && x % 10 == 3:
                            return "rd"
                        default:
                            return "th"
                        }
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }

                return ""
            }

            return "\(self)" + ordinalSuffix(self)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the solutions here don't handle higher numbers like 112. Here is a simple way to do it.

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
    int n = i;
    NSString* ordinal = @"th";
    if(n%10==1 && n%100!=11) ordinal = @"st";
    if(n%10==2 && n%100!=12) ordinal = @"nd";
    if(n%10==3 && n%100!=13) ordinal = @"rd";
    NSLog(@"You are the %d%@",i,ordinal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short Int extension for the English language that also accounts for and displays negative integers correctly:

```
extension Int {
    func ordinal() -> String {
        let suffix: String!
        // treat negative numbers as positive for suffix
        let number = (self < 0 ? self * -1 : self)

        switch number % 10 {
        case 0:
            suffix = self != 0 ? "th" : ""
        case 1:
            suffix = "st"
        case 2:
            suffix = "nd"
        case 3:
            suffix = "rd"
        default:
            suffix = "th"
        }

        return String(self) + suffix
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *) formatOrdinalNumber:(NSInteger )number{
    NSString *result = nil;
    //0 remains just 0
    if (number == 0) {
        result = @"0";
    }

    //test for number between 3 and 21 as they follow a
    //slightly different rule and all end with th
    else if (number > 3 && number < 21)
    {
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld th",(long)number];
    }
    else {
        //return the last digit of the number e.g. 102 is 2
        NSInteger lastdigit = number % 10;
        switch (lastdigit)
        {
            case 1: result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld st",(long)number]; break;
            case 2: result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld nd",(long)number]; break;
            case 3: result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld rd",(long)number]; break;
            default: result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld th",(long)number];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, Its well simplified.

```
function numberToOrdinal(n) {

  if (n==0) {
    return n;
   }
   var j = n % 10,
       k = n % 100;


   if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
       return n + "st";
   }
   if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
       return n + "nd";
   }
   if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
       return n + "rd";
   }
   return n + "th";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public extension Int {
 var ordinalValue: String? {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self))
 }
}
```

Don't forget to add the Locale, if it is not added, it won't work.
Usage:

```
let number = 2
let ordinalNumber = number.ordinalValue
print(ordinalNumber) //It will print 2nd
```

Answer (score -4):

This was my brute force implementation to taking a NSString* representation of the date and returning the ordinal value.  I feel it's much easier to read.

```
NSDictionary *ordinalDates = @{
    @"1": @"1st",
    @"2": @"2nd",
    @"3": @"3rd",
    @"4": @"4th",
    @"5": @"5th",
    @"6": @"6th",
    @"7": @"7th",
    @"8": @"8th",
    @"9": @"9th",
    @"10": @"10th",
    @"11": @"11th",
    @"12": @"12th",
    @"13": @"13th",
    @"14": @"14th",
    @"15": @"15th",
    @"16": @"16th",
    @"17": @"17th",
    @"18": @"18th",
    @"19": @"19th",
    @"20": @"20th",
    @"21": @"21st",
    @"22": @"22nd",
    @"23": @"23rd",
    @"24": @"24th",
    @"25": @"25th",
    @"26": @"26th",
    @"27": @"27th",
    @"28": @"28th",
    @"29": @"29th",
    @"30": @"30th",
    @"31": @"31st" };
```

Comment: How long does the list go?

Comment: A lot of strings