# Integer Extensions - 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc

Tags: iphone, cocoa, integer, ordinals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [NSNumberFormatter and ‘th’ ‘st’ ‘nd’ ‘rd’ (ordinal) number endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312935/nsnumberformatter-and-th-st-nd-rd-ordinal-number-endings)

Hello,

I'm building an application that downloads player ranks and displays them. So say for example, you're 3rd out of all the players, I inserted a condition that will display it as 3rd, not 3th and i did the same for 2nd and 1st. When getting to higher ranks though, such as 2883rd, it'll display 2883th (for obvious reasons)

My question is, how can I get it to reformat the number to XXX1st, XXX2nd, XXX3rd etc?

To show what I mean, here's how I format my number to add a "rd" if it's 3

```
if ([[container stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@"3"])
{
    NSString*badge = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@rd",[container stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    NSString*scoreText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ROC Server Rank: %@rd",[container stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    profile.badgeValue = badge;
    rank.text = scoreText;
}
```

I can't do this for every number up to 2000 (there are 2000 ranks in total) - what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the obvious reason for displaying the ordinal as 2883th ?  When I read it I say 'two-thousand eight-hundred and eighty-third', rather than 'two-thousand eight-hundred and eighty-threeth'.

Comment: Already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312935/nsnumberformatter-and-th-st-nd-rd-ordinal-number-endings

Comment: ...Why suddenly everyone wants to ordinalize a number recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it check the last digit of every number then add the suffix accordingly.

Checking the last 2 digits will fix it.

Comment: It's not just the last digit that gives the ordination.  3 is different than 13, but the same as 133

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short snippet in another language: http://www.bytechaser.com/en/functions/b6yhfyxh78/convert-number-to-ordinal-like-1st-2nd-in-c-sharp.aspx

```
/// <summary>
/// Create an ordinal number from any number 
/// e.g. 1 becomes 1st and 22 becomes 22nd
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">Number to convert</param>
/// <returns>Ordinal value as string</returns>
public static string FormatOrdinalNumber(int number)
{
    //0 remains just 0
    if (number == 0) return "0";
    //test for number between 3 and 21 as they follow a 
    //slightly different rule and all end with th            
    if (number > 3 && number < 21)
    {
        return number + "th";
    }
    //return the last digit of the number e.g. 102 is 2
    var lastdigit = number % 10;
    //append the correct ordinal val
    switch (lastdigit)
    {
        case 1: return number + "st";
        case 2: return number + "nd";
        case 3: return number + "rd";
        default: return number + "th";
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails for 112, etc.  This would return 112nd, but it should be 112th.

Comment: the above code was updated on the bytechaser.com site to be a bit neater and should work with all numbers