# Format number as ranking position

Tags: c#, formatting, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way in .NET to get “st”, “nd”, “rd” and “th” endings for numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262/is-there-an-easy-way-in-net-to-get-st-nd-rd-and-th-endings-for-numbers)

Is there anything already built into C# that formats a number as a ranking position?

By "ranking position" is mean one of ["st","nd,"rd","th"] eg : (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th).

I know it'd be easy to write an extension for this, I'm just wondering if there is already something in the language to cater.

Cheers

Comment: Have a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262/is-there-an-easy-way-in-net-to-get-st-nd-rd-and-th-endings-for-numbers.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing built-in for this purpose. Not sure if its relevant, but consider cultural differences if you span languages/cultures.

Comment: Thanks Jamiec. In considering cultures I'm thinking of storing the ordinal specifier in a resouce file so that we can specify specific ones for certain cultures. What do you think of this as a solution?

Answer (score -2):

I've been corrected. Please see the duplicate questions as described in the comments above.

<strike>Not out-of-the-box; however, as you mentioned, an extension is pretty easy.</strike>

```
public static string ConvertToRankingPosition(this int value)
{
    var digit = value % 10;
    return value != 11 && digit == 1 : value + "st" :
           value != 12 && digit == 2 : value + "nd" :
           value != 13 && digit == 3 : value + "rd" :
           value + "th"
}
```

Comment: needs to handle 11,12, and 13

Comment: There appear to be some corner cases that your code doesn't incorporate. Have a look at the answers to the duplicate questions.

Comment: Ill put it here as everyone else has in all the other similar SO questions; Your method is broken as 1011 returns 1011st.