# How to convert the string into specified date format

Tags: c#, date

Hello i want to convert my date like following format--
1st JUN 2012,
3rd MAR 2012,
11th JUN 2012

```
    Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"]).ToString("d MMM yyyy")
```

but with above code i am getting like this

1 JUN 2012,
3 MAR 2012,
 please help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: Check this out,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c

Comment: Custom date formatting is avalible here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx
however what you are asking about doesn't exist since different langauges use different letters for "st", "nd", "rd" etc.
Your going to have to write something yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way in .NET to get "st", "nd", "rd" and "th" endings for numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262/is-there-an-easy-way-in-net-to-get-st-nd-rd-and-th-endings-for-number)

Comment: In spanish ordinals can be represented by º if you are referencing a no sex deterministic word or a masculine word, some sex neutral words are represented with er after int, in femenine is ª Your solution only will be work to an English target, example 1ª puerta, ha quedado 1º o 1er piso (1st door, finished 1st,1st flat

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but it should work:

```
DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"]);
string date = string.Format("{0}{1} {2} {3}", dateTime.Day, GetOrdinal(dateTime.Day), dateTime.ToString("MMM"), datetTime.Year);

public string GetOrdinal(int number)
{
        switch(number % 100)
        {
            case 11:
            case 12:
            case 13:
                    return "th";
        }
        switch(number % 10)
        {
                case 1:
                        return "st";
                case 2:
                        return "nd";
                case 3:
                        return "rd";
                default:
                        return "th";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't, according to this: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with a format string. You will have to convert the day number by yourself. There's an approach described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20175/350749).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use "st", "nd", "rd", "th" etc. there is no other way then using swtich operator:

```
switch(yourdate.Day % 10)
  case(1): ...
  case(2): ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this,

```
string strPostfix = string.Empty;
if (DateTime.Now.Day == 1 || DateTime.Now.Day == 21 || DateTime.Now.Day == 31)
    {
    strPostfix = "st";
    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.Day == 2 || DateTime.Now.Day == 22)
    {
    strPostfix = "nd";
    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.Day == 3 || DateTime.Now.Day == 23)
    {
    strPostfix = "rd";
    }
    else
    {
    strPostfix = "th";
    }
```

Hope this will help you, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Since ordinals are very much language specific, it is not recommended to use them!
However, if you must, it should be pretty straightforward to write a switch statement to take care of it. (If it is really important to you)

Then you could split your string at spaces, process the first part, and merge the string again

Answer (score 0):

Please, to google a little... there are solutions published
http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/07/15/find-the-ordinal-representation-of-an-integer-1st-2nd-3rd-in-c.aspx