# C# convert Datetime to Thursday, 26th July 2014 format

Tags: .net, datetime, formatting

I want to convert a DateTime variable to the following format: "Thursday, 26th July 2014".

What would be the right approach.

Thanks

Comment: `DateTime.ToString(<someformat>)`, you'll find all you need about the format here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You may also read this for the `th` part : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601593/how-can-i-format-07-03-2012-to-march-7th-2012-in-c-sharp

Comment: Here's a better link for the ordinal number format: http://stackoverflow.com/q/69262/634824

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to separate the parts before and behind `th` from each other:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 07, 26);
string result = string.Format("{1}{0} {2}",
    dt.Day == 1 ? "st" : dt.Day == 2 ? "nd" : dt.Day == 3 ? "rd" : "th",
    dt.ToString("dddd, dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    dt.ToString("MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

If you don't really need your exact format you can also use `DateTime` methods like [`ToLongDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring.aspx) which uses the current culture and has a fixed format.

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDN [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this produces a "Long" date pattern

```
DateTime.ToString("D")
```