# To 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th (Month days)

Tags: c#, .net

I have written an extension function to determine if a month day/number is 1st/31st, 2nd/22nd, 3rd or 4th....30th.

I would like to find out if there is a better/shorter or elegant way I could've written it? My function:

```
/// <summary>
/// To 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th (Month days)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="n"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string To1st2nd3rd4th( this double n )
{
    // nFirst
    if ( new double[] { 1, 21, 31 }.Contains( n ) )
    {
        return $"{n}st";
    }

    // nSecond
    if ( new double[] { 2, 22 }.Contains( n ) )
    {
        return $"{n}nd";
    }

    // nThird
    if ( n == 3 )
    {
        return $"{n}rd";
    }

    //n-th/ n > 3
    if ( n > 3 )
    {
        return $"{n}th";
    }

    return n.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way in .NET to get "st", "nd", "rd" and "th" endings for numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262/is-there-an-easy-way-in-net-to-get-st-nd-rd-and-th-endings-for-number)

Comment: If your code works and you seek constructive criticism or improvements, ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: If all of the conditions (`if` statements) are mutually exclusive, use `else if` instead. Also, the last condition is the equivalent of just an `else`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601593/how-can-i-format-07-03-2012-to-march-7th-2012-in-c-sharp

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c

Comment: This works, but there's already and extensive library that will do this and much more: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer
Edit: Look for 'Ordinalize' in the Table of Contents.

Comment: Most of the solutions I have come across seem to have too much code and were answered many years back. I thought by 2019 we would've a better solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for improvements to working code should be asked on [CodeReview.se] instead.

Comment: I created a simple method to add this suffix.  Please see my answer below.  I do not see this question in code review.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has few problems.

First of all, why does the day (seeing as it is a date) has to be `double`? So I'd use an `int` there.

Second, your `if` statements can be `if-else`. You'll have to add a case for it being negative or zero.

But this has the problem of not working for numbers such as `33` (sure, there isn't a 33rd day of the month, but a function should be self sufficient).

I'd rather use the [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) library which can do this and much more.

You can get the `NuGet` package, and once done it's as easy as:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", 1, 1.Ordinalize());
Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", 21, 21.Ordinalize());
Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", 31, 31.Ordinalize());
Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", 33, 33.Ordinalize());
Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", 2, 22.Ordinalize());
Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", 3, 3.Ordinalize());
Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", 4, 4.Ordinalize());
Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", 55, 55.Ordinalize());
Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", 1237, 1237.Ordinalize());
Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", 0, 0.Ordinalize());
```

### Output

> 1 ==> 1st
>
> 21 ==> 21st
>
> 31 ==> 31st
>
> 33 ==> 33rd
>
> 2 ==> 22nd
>
> 3 ==> 3rd
>
> 4 ==> 4th
>
> 55 ==> 55th
>
> 1237 ==> 1237th
>
> 0 ==> 0th

Answer (score 0):

```
  private string NumberSuffix(double n)
    {
        var below100 = n % 10;
        var above100 = n % 100;

        if (below100 == 1 && above100 != 11)
        {
            return n + "st";
        }
        if (below100 == 2 && above100 != 12)
        {
            return n + "nd";
        }
        if (below100 == 3 && above100 != 13)
        {
            return n + "rd";
        }
        return n + "th";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you as a general method:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(0, 24).Select(NumberSuffix)));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(250, 24).Select(NumberSuffix)));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(10001, 24).Select(NumberSuffix)));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string NumberSuffix2(int n)
    {
        //                           0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9      10    11    12
        string[] nth = new string[] {"th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th"};

        int n2 = Math.Abs(n);

        return n + nth[(n2 % 100) % (n2 % 100 > 13 ? 10 : 13)];
    }
```

Output is:

0th 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th 9th 10th 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th 17th 18th 19th 20th 21st 22nd 23rd

250th 251st 252nd 253rd 254th 255th 256th 257th 258th 259th 260th 261st 262nd 263rd 264th 265th 266th 267th 268th 269th 270th 271st 272nd 273rd

0001st 10002nd 10003rd 10004th 10005th 10006th 10007th 10008th 10009th 10010th 10011th 10012th 10013th 10014th 10015th 10016th 10017th 10018th 10019th 10020th 10021st 10022nd 10023rd 10024th

Comment: `11st`, `12nd`, and `13rd` are new ones to me... :)

Comment: I edited to compensate for 11, 12, 13, etc.  Thanks for pointing that out Rufus L

Comment: Did you test that with numbers like 100001? I don't think it scales.

Comment: I'll check this out when I get home from work but it should work.  The one line reduces the number to between 0 & 99 regardless of the original value - and I just realized that I need to replace this with Modulus 100.  I will simplify tonight

Comment: As I expected, the original code worked correctly and produces the same output as the modified code.  The above edited code also works (output included) but now is a bit more compact and uses less steps.