# Is there a VB.NET function to format a number as an Ordinal

Tags: vb.net, function, numbers, ordinals

Is there a built in VB.NET function to format a number as an Ordinal or do I have to write my own?

[There isn't in C# so I'm thinking there isn't :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/ordinals-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an implementation were available for VB.NET, it would be available for C# as well - you can call into the VB-specific "standard libraries" from C#.

In other words - I don't believe there's anything in the framework.

Answer (score 11):

Already answered in [Ordinals in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/ordinals-in-c)
Search is your friend . . .

Basically "No, there is no method provided in the framework", but there are good answers about how to do it.

**EDIT**

Apologies to whom ever thought I deserved the downvote, I should have translated the C# to vb.net.

```
Public Function AddOrdinal(ByVal num As Integer) as String
    Select Case (num Mod 100)
        Case 11 To 13
            Return num.ToString() & "th"
    End Select
    Select Case num Mod 10
        Case 1
            Return num.ToString() & "st"
        Case 2
            Return num.ToString() & "nd"
        Case 3
            Return num.ToString() & "rd"
        Case Else
            Return num.ToString() & "th"
    End Select
End Function
```