# How to convert number to arabic word in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, currency, ordinal

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there an easy way to create ordinals in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c)
>   [How can I convert an integer into its verbal representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation)

Hi All,

How to convert number to arabic word?
I want output like:
1: First
2: Second,
201: Two hundred first etc

I have try some code but it words for 1..21,23...31,33...41,43..49,51... and then after it does not work.
Is there any special logic for converting **2** in arabic?

Please give me some idea for converting number to word.

Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: The word you want isn't "arabic," it's "ordinal" -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_%28linguistics%29

Comment: Someone else suggested this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112949/Number-To-Word-Arabic-Version as a source of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-closed) previous SO Post on how to change numbers into words.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want ordinal for arabic number. And the previous post is for english.