# Convert 1st day string to Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm looking for a way to be able to convert a date string like this:

```
"1st Oct 2018" => 2018-10-01
```

Or this:

```
"10th Mar 2015" => 2015-03-10
```

To it's equivalent `string` in the format `yyyy mm dd`. I have tried the following code, but no luck:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "yyyy mm dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: do you see the gap between `10th Mar 2015` and `"yyyy mm dd"`

Comment: "yyyy mm dd" isn't a target format, it's the current format of the date. DateTime objects do not have any formatting themselves, and merely format the date when it's converted to a string, either through `ToString()` (or similar), or through the debugger display.

Comment: [Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710561/parse-very-long-date-format-to-datetime-in-c-sharp) - you need to remove the "dddd" part of course.

Comment: I think you have to remove the “st” “nd” “th” with a function, because I have read another question with the opposite problem and there is no built-in function in the datetime class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in addition to great answer from Daisy:

```
[TestCase("15th Oct 2018")]
[TestCase("1st Oct 2018")]
[TestCase("2nd Oct 2018")]
[TestCase("3rd Oct 2018")]
[TestCase("3d Oct 2018")]
public void Action(string dateStr)
{
    // Act
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Regex.Replace(dateStr, "(th|st|nd|rd|d)", ""), "d MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    //Assert
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

UPD: added great suggestions from Dmitry Bychenko.

Comment: `Regex.Replace(dateStr, "(th|st|nd|rd)", "")` is a bit shorter (no need to `new`)

Comment: Thanks. How can I get a format like 2018-10-01 in output? Can you please consider this as well?

Comment: We often out it as `3d Oct`, not `3rd Oct`

Comment: I suppose, that `DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` should handle values like 2018-10-01.

Comment: @KozhevnikovDmitry No, it doesn't!

Comment: Or how can I convert it to  2018-10-01 in string?

Comment: @J.P: `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Answer (score 2):

A `DateTime` value doesn't have a format - it's just a value. (Just like an `int` isn't inherently decimal or hex - you choose how to format it when you convert it to a string, and the default is to use decimal.)

The string you're passing into `DateTime.ParseExact` is the expected *input* format - and your strings don't have the format "yyyy mm dd". (Note that in date/time format strings, "mm" means minutes, so you'd want "MM" instead of "mm" anyway... but that won't help here.)

Your date format is *nearly* "d MMM yyyy" (day, short month name, year) using English month names - but the problem is the ordinal part ("st", "nd", "th"). As far as I know there's no simple way of handling that with `DateTime.ParseExact`. Instead, I'd probably use a regular expression or simple string replacement to remove the ordinal part, so that you *do* have a string in the format "d MMM yyyy" and then parse that.

For the string replacement part, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710561) are appropriate. So here's a complete example using your sample data:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ParseWithOrdinals("10th Mar 2015"));
        Console.WriteLine(ParseWithOrdinals("1st Oct 2018"));
    }

    private static DateTime ParseWithOrdinals(string input) =>
        DateTime.ParseExact(
            RemoveOrdinals(input), // Text to parse
            "d MMM yyyy",          // Format of text
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Expect English month names, Gregorian calendar


    // From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710561
    private static string RemoveOrdinals(string input) =>
        input
            .Replace("0th", "0")
            .Replace("1st", "1")
            .Replace("2nd", "2")
            .Replace("3rd", "3")
            .Replace("11th", "11") // Need to handle these separately...
            .Replace("12th", "12")
            .Replace("13th", "13")
            .Replace("4th", "4")
            .Replace("5th", "5")
            .Replace("6th", "6")
            .Replace("7th", "7")
            .Replace("8th", "8")
            .Replace("9th", "9");
}
```

(Note that I haven't formatted the result as yyyy-MM-dd in the output, so you'll get your local date/time format.)

Comment: Thanks. How can I get a format like 2018-10-01 in output? Can you please consider this as well?

Comment: @J.P: You'd then want to look at how to format a `DateTime` to a string, which is a different matter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983 is a good starting point.

Comment: @fubo: You can escape *specific* characters; you can't write a pattern that says "The next character is s or t" for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a native approach without string remove / replace / Regex

If you know the characters, you can escape them with the `'` character inside the date pattern. So `"15th Oct 2018"` works for this pattern `"d'th' MMM yyyy"`

Now there are `"st","nd","rd","th"` so you can try each of them and chose the working one.

Into the overload of [`TryParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact) you can pass a range of allowable formats.

```
string input = "15th Oct 2018";
DateTime result = DateTime.Now;
string[] patterns = { "d'st' MMM yyyy", "d'nd' MMM yyyy", "d'rd' MMM yyyy", "d'th' MMM yyyy"};
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(input, patterns, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
if (success)
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/H8ulyo