# Date With Endings

Tags: c#, date

I am trying to get the current date, which works with the code that I have at the moment:

```
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && InputTextbox.Text == "date")            
{
    OutputTextbox.Text = "Today is " + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd");
    pBuilder.ClearContent();
    pBuilder.AppendText(OutputTextbox.Text);
    sSynth.Speak(pBuilder);
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    InputTextbox.Text = ""; 
}
```

That gives me the date as a number (ie: 26).

I have done some research on other ways to put the "th", "rd", and "nd" on the end of the numbers, but is there a way to do this within the current "else if" statement that I have at the moment (the other solutions are in a seperate space).

Comment: that functionality does not exist in .net.

Comment: There's a nice answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4544313/1517578

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider modifying your code to include the following snippet of code...

```
string date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd");
    date = date + (date.EndsWith("11") 
                   ? "th"
                   : date.EndsWith("12")
                   ? "th"
                   : date.EndsWith("13")
                   ? "th"
                   : date.EndsWith("1") 
                   ? "st"
                   : date.EndsWith("2")
                   ? "nd"
                   : date.EndsWith("3")
                   ? "rd"
                   : "th");
```

Good Luck!

Comment: +1 i really do not know how to use the ? : syntax.. great solution than mine! :)

Comment: Thanks! I like yours too. Different approaches same solution ;)

Comment: what is the meaning of ? : is that lambda expression? i want to know how to use that.

Comment: This answer produces incorrect results 11st, 12nd, and 13rd.

Comment: ?: is shorthand for if else. The following link should explain...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: ahhh mine to would produce incorrect :)

Comment: drf...the condition needs to be expanded. I will update the solution

Comment: Wow - that was a great answer. Worked perfectly. The only other thing I added was:
> if (int.Parse(date) < 10)
> {
> date = date.Substring(1,1);
< }

That changed the "01" values to "1"