# Formatting a DateTime value Day value

Tags: datetime, .net-3.5, ordinals

Is there a simple method of displaying the day portion of a date in the format 1st, 2nd, 3rd,…? I suspect that there is no method of doing this through custom datetime formatstrings (I will be very happy to be wrong), so has anyone implemented a way of doing this?

Comment: What language and .net version are you using ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c

Comment: @Misnomer - using .Net 3.5 at the moment. I'll take answers in any .Net language.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - thanks for the link. I'll take a look and see if I implement a similar solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the core logic for achieving this end:

```
string SuffixForDay(DateTime date) {
    switch (date.Day) {
        case 1:
        case 21:
        case 31:
            return "st";
        case 2:
        case 22:
            return "nd";
        case 3:
        case 23:
            return "rd";
        default:
            return "th";
     }
 }
```

Comment: +1 - For simple code..(and for previous comment on my deleted answer !)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime.Day](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day.aspx) property for this purpose.

Comment: ...and write code to add the suffix dynamically: st, nd, rd, th (it seems there are only 4 cases)

Comment: Day would just return the integer value not the suffix "st", "rd", "th" etc