# What dateTime format is compatible with both .NET and JS without any further need of reformatting?

Tags: javascript, .net, datetime

I am making a web application, and I need a DateTime format that is both compatible with JS Date and .NET DateTime, which are outlined differently on the following two pages:

JS Format:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

.NET Format:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.71).aspx

As you can see, they are similar, but not exactly the same.  The one I would like to use in JS is "**mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT**", but there is no equivalent of this format in .NET much to my dismay.  Is there any other format I could use that would work in both JS and .NET without any need of reformatting when passed between the two languages?

Answer (score 1):

Surely its a relatively straight forward jobs to standardize the formatting flags between .net and JS?

**Update based on comment**

The OP wanted to format dates in JS like so:

`dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
// Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM`

To format a date in a similar format in .NET you could do something like: (more info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
myBirthday.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy, h:MM:ss tt");
// Saturday, June 9, 2007, 5:46:21 PM
```

You'll see the day doesn't include the ordinal suffix - for that refer to [Is there an easy way to create ordinals in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c)

Comment: How about an actual implementation in an answer?

Answer (score -1):

When using date objects between two systems, the ideal approach is to use the ISO 8601 format.  Unfortunately not all JS implementations support ISO 8601 (Webkit-based ones for example).

[This blog](http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/) has a good idea.  Add an object to the date objects prototype, to handle ISO 8601 dates correctly.

Comment: Blog link is broken.