# Find the weekday of month by date

Tags: c#, datetime, weekday

I am trying to find the number of weekday of month by passing a date in C#.

For ex.: If I pass "3/6/2013 (6-Mar-2013)" the function should say 1st wednesday of month.
If I pass "3/1/2013 (1-Mar-2013)" the function should say 1st friday of month.
If I pass "3/13/2013 (13-Mar-2013)" the function should say 2nd wednesday of month.

I was trying to use this function, but its returning the week of month(i.e. passing "3/6/2013 (6-Mar-2013)" returns 2):

```
public static int GetWeekOfMonth(DateTime date)
        {
            DateTime beginningOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);

            while (date.Date.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek != CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
                date = date.AddDays(1);

            return (int)Math.Truncate((double)date.Subtract(beginningOfMonth).TotalDays / 7f) + 1;
        }
```

Please suggest on how to get the number of weekday of month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I threw together real quick:

```
public static int GetWeekOfMonth(DateTime dateTime)
{
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = dateTime.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime dayStep = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
    int returnValue = 0;

    while (dayStep <= dateTime)
    {
        if (dayStep.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)
        {
            returnValue++;
        }

        dayStep = dayStep.AddDays(1);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Here is the same method, only it returns a string such as "1st", "2nd", "3rd", etc, instead of a simple INT.  The ordinal code is based on samjudson's code on this post: [Is there an easy way to create ordinals in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c)

```
public static string GetWeekOfMonth(DateTime dateTime)
{
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = dateTime.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime dayStep = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
    int returnValue = 0;

    while (dayStep <= dateTime)
    {
        if (dayStep.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)
        {
            returnValue++;
        }

        dayStep = dayStep.AddDays(1);
    }

    switch (returnValue % 100)
    {
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
            return returnValue.ToString() + "th";
    }

    switch (returnValue % 10)
    {
        case 1:
            return returnValue.ToString() + "st";
        case 2:
            return returnValue.ToString() + "nd";
        case 3:
            return returnValue.ToString() + "rd";
        default:
            return returnValue.ToString() + "th";
    }
}
```

And finally, this will return "2nd Wednesday of month":

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-13");
string dateString = string.Format("{0} {1} of month", GetWeekOfMonth(dt), dt.ToString("dddd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int GetWeekOfMonth(DateTime date)
{
  var weekDay = date.DayOfWeek;
  var nth = date.Day / 7;
  if (date.Day % 7 > 0)
  {
    nth++;
  }
  return nth;
}
```

**Edit:**
`var weekDay...` is actually not needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple, I think. If the day of month is `1` through `7`, the result is `1`, if the day of month is `8` through `14`, it's `2`, and so on. Therefore:

```
public static int GetWeekOfMonth(DateTime date)
{
    return (date.Day + 6) / 7;
}
```

This works because of the way division `/` is defined when the operands (dividend and divisor) are integers, see [`/` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx).