# how to get a custom dateTime format string in c#

Tags: c#

I want to get this specific dateformat in c# `Friday Nov 29th 2013` how can i achieve that ?

```
DateTime.Now.toString("//what should i write here ");
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dddd MMM dd'th' yyyy` format like;

```
string s = "Friday Nov 29th 2013";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dddd MMM dd'th' yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Output will be;

```
11/29/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Here a [`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/W88woN).

For more informations, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

**EDIT**: Okey, looks like I little bit misunderstand your question. There is no standart format for `"st"`, `"nd"`, `"th"` in .NET.

You can use

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd MMM dd'th' yyyy");
```

but this works only for this case. When your day is `1`, you get `1th` instead of `1st`.

Here is the pattern:

```
If the units digit is:  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
write this number:      th  st  nd  rd  th  th  th  th  th  th
```

But also this pattern is not usefull because `11th` but `21st`. Looks like your only chance writing your own specific cases.

Comment: Parse doesn't have the same format as ToString(), the former is richer.

Comment: I read the question as asking how to format and existing DateTime in this way, not how to parse an existing string into a DateTime. This answer currently shows parsing.

Comment: i found the solution and it's : DateTime.Now.toString("dddd MMM dd'<sup>th</sup>' yyyy") thank you

Comment: @Sora But this works only in this case. When your day will be `1` for example, you get `1th` instead of `1st`.

Comment: @Sora, `"dddd MMM dd'<sup>th</sup>' yyyy"` will output the wrong value for 2013-12-01. On that day, you'll want to output "Sunday Dec 1*st* 2013" not "Sunday Dec 1*th* 2013". [Ordinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals#Ordinal_numbers) don't always end with "th".

Comment: aren't there a global way to do this ? or i should write a hard code on my own to globalize it

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom format provider to get this specific dateformat **"Friday Nov 29th 2013"**

```
public class SuffiexFormattedDateProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an object that provides formatting services for the specified type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="formatType">An object that specifies the type of format object to return.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An instance of the object specified by <paramref name="formatType" />, if the <see cref="T:System.IFormatProvider" /> implementation can supply that type of object; otherwise, null.
    /// </returns>
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the value of a specified object to an equivalent string representation using specified format and culture-specific formatting information.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="format">A format string containing formatting specifications.</param>
    /// <param name="arg">An object to format.</param>
    /// <param name="formatProvider">An object that supplies format information about the current instance.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The string representation of the value of <paramref name="arg" />, formatted as specified by <paramref name="format" /> and <paramref name="formatProvider" />.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.NotSupportedException"></exception>
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (!(arg is DateTime)) throw new NotSupportedException();

        var dt = (DateTime)arg;

        string suffix;

        if (dt.Day % 10 == 1)
        {
            suffix = "st";
        }
        else if (dt.Day % 10 == 2)
        {
            suffix = "nd";
        }
        else if (dt.Day % 10 == 3)
        {
            suffix = "rd";
        }
        else
        {
            suffix = "th";
        }

        return string.Format("{0:dddd MMM} {1}{2}, {0:yyyy}", arg, dt.Day, suffix);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this as

```
string formatDateString = string.Format(new SuffiexFormattedDateProvider(), "{0}",   DateTime.Now);
```

Output:- **"Friday Nov 29th, 2013"**

Answer (score 0):

D? F? It depends what kind of format you want!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("D"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> `DateTime.Now.toString("//what should i write here ");`

If we are limited to just `DateTime.ToString(string)`, I am not aware of any way to do this. There is no [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) that performs the "st", "nd", "rd", "th" computation for [English ordinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals#Ordinal_numbers)

I'd see if you can get the requirements changed so that you don't have to worry about "st", "nd", "rd" and "th". If you must format in this way, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd MMM dd'th' yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article, should have what you want

```
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/
```

from that article:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are lazy like me you could just do this.....

```
// Lets create a date to work with.
DateTime DT1 = DateTime.Now;

// Create a holding string, and add the day name, with a comma and then the day.
string FormattedDatestringThing = DT.ToString("dddd") + ", " + DT1.Day.ToString());

// Now lets add the "st", "nd", "rd" or "th" depending on the day value.
switch (DT1.Day)
{
    case 1:
    case 21:
    case 31:
        FormattedDatestringThing += "st";  // So if it's 1, 21 or 31 then add "st".
        break;
    case 2:
    case 22:
        FormattedDatestringThing += "nd";  // If it's 2 or 22 then add "nd".
        break;
    case 3:
    case 23:
        FormattedDatestringThing += "rd";  // If it's 3 or 23 then add "rd".
        break;
    default:
        FormattedDatestringThing += "th";  // Otherwise write out "th".
        break;
}

// Finaly add the year to the string and we are done.
FormattedDatestringThing += " " + DT1.ToString("yyyy"));
```

Easy enough to stick into a function if needed.
Note: This is the lazy mans way of doing a "just get it working".