# How to append th, st, nd and rd for dates of the day in rdlc report?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, rdlc, date-format

I'm working with certifications and I need to append date of the day suffixes. I tried using `=Day(Fields!Date.value)` in the expression property of the TextBox but the output is just a number/date of the day but has no suffix. I have no problem in Month and Year only the suffixes in the date of the day. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggestion in [Is there an easy way to create ordinals in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20175/5104101) you can create a `Custom Code` for your rdlc report and use it with the expression.

1. In the rdlc properties add the following function in *Code* tab

   ```
   Public Shared Function AddOrdinal(num As Integer) As String
       If num <= 0 Then
           Return num.ToString()
       End If
       Select Case num Mod 100
           Case 11, 12, 13
               Return num & "th"
       End Select
       Select Case num Mod 10
           Case 1
               Return num & "st"
           Case 2
               Return num & "nd"
           Case 3
               Return num & "rd"
           Case Else
               Return num & "th"
       End Select
   End Function
   ```
2. Then modify your *Expression* as follows

   ```
   =Code.AddOrdinal(Day(Fields!Date.value))
   ```

Comment: Thank you! You saved my life! Oh God you're so great!

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your data set you could add the following fields to split the date into a day, suffix and Month / Year:

```
select Cast(DAY(Date) as Varchar(2)) as MthDay, DATENAME(month, Date) + ' ' + convert(varchar(4),year(Date)) as MthYr,
CASE WHEN DAY(Date) in (1,21,31) THEN 'st' WHEN DAY(Date) IN (2,22) then 'nd' WHEN DAY(Date) IN (3,23) then 'rd' ELSE 'th ' end as Suffix
From MyData
```

You could then use three text fields in your report to display the date with the suffix text being set to say 6pt and set to display at the top of the field.

Alternatively you could use one text field set to allow HTML tags and join the the three parts together using the sup tag to display the suffix appropriately.