# How to properly make a ranking/leaderboard page in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to find a more detailed way to display rank for my movie website.
This is my Movie.cs model

```
public int MovieId { get; set; }
public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
public int ViewCounter { get; set; }
```

I have **ViewCounter** which I use to count how many people visited to watch that specific Movie.
This is my Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Ranking()
        {
            var item = from m in databaseContext.Movies.Include("Genre").Include("Director")
                       where m.IsHidden == false
                       orderby m.ViewCounter descending
                       select m;
            return View(item.ToList());
        }
```

This is the View for that Controller:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebXemPhim.Models.Domain.Movie>

<div class="blog-list-area section pt-100 pt-lg-80 pt-md-70 pt-sm-60 pt-xs-50 pb-xs-50">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-25">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="row">

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
        <div class="col-12">
            <!--Single Blog Post Start-->
            <div class="single-blog-post blog-list mb-30">
                <div class="blog-img">
                    <a href="single-blog.html"><img src="~/images/@item.MovieImageName" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <div class="blog-content">
                    <h3><a href="single-blog.html">@item.MovieTitle</a></h3>
                    <p>@item.MoviePlot</p>
                    <div class="blog-bottom">
                        <ul class="meta meta-border-bottom">
                            <li><a>@item.ViewCounter</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Single Blog Post End-->
        </div>}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Blog Area End-->
```

So far it's good, but now it's missing the RANK NUMBER ( like 1,2,3,4)(the movie with the highest views will be 1) and I just don't how to actually add an extra column with LINQ. Any suggestions? Or should I just make a new column that store RANK for each movie instead?

Answer (score 0):

Given you want to display an order of a property you already have then just do

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(m => m.ViewCounter))
```

Comment: thank you but I've already done this. What I'm missing in my page is to display the number that shows the rank of my items. for example for a top 10, number one will be the highest, number 10 will be the lowest.

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is called Ordinal Numbers. To add the ordinal number ranking for each movie, you'll probably want to dynamically create a tuple or something similar in your controller and have that display in your view. As for actually creating the ordinal numbers, there's some examples here -> [Is there an easy way to create ordinals in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

> So far it's good, but now it's missing the RANK NUMBER ( like
> 1,2,3,4)(the movie with the highest views will be 1) and I just don't
> how to actually add an extra column with LINQ. Any suggestions? Or
> should I just make a new column that store RANK for each movie
> instead?

From your description, it seems that you want to display the Rank Number based on the ViewCounter, right?

To display the RankNumber base on the ViewCounter, first, you could create a MovieViewModel view model with the Ranking property, this view model only used to display the Movie model.

```
public class MovieViewModel
{
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
    public int ViewCounter { get; set; }
    public string Ranking { get; set; }
}
```

In the Linq Statement, after ordering the data, you could get the order index, and then according the value to set the RankNumber:

```
    public IActionResult Ranking()
    {
        //get the movie list
        List<Movie> movies = _InitData.GetMovie();

        var result = movies.OrderByDescending(c => c.ViewCounter)
            .Select((c, index) => new MovieViewModel
            {
                MovieId = c.MovieId,
                MovieTitle = c.MovieTitle,
                ViewCounter = c.ViewCounter,
                Ranking = index < 5 ? "1" : index < 10 ? "2" : index < 15 ? "3" : "4" //based on the index to set ranking
            }); 
        return View(result);
    }
```

After rendering, the output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either add it as a column in the DB (which I think is way less dynamic) or you can dynamically add a column in the view, with a for loop.